# Nothing appears when calling data from the database when uploading query

Tags: php, mysql

am using localhost and database from phpmyadmin

in php

```
    <?php
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=site_1", "root", "");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comment_v1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $avatars = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($avatars);
    ?>
```

in output

Array ( )

am working on games download site and i created 4 tables for now and all scripts working 100% without pb and the query the same but when i try to SELECT anything from table comment_v1 his apears nothing and idk the reason so i try to disable all the old query in scripts but the same result i got , but when i try code to SELECT the old query again his shows nothing with knowing that old query still working for now and idk why when i try to SELECT them again his show me nothing

Comment: Just to be sure, the part in your code example that says "enter code here" is not actually in your code right?  That's just a place holder for posting to Stack Overflow?  Because if it is in your code and not commented out, it could mess up the next line.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding an execute() function before the fetchAll()?

something like:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=site_1", "root", "");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comment_v1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt = $stmt->execute();
    $avatars = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($avatars);
?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).